# WordPress Post Meta instead of title in Custom Post Type Permalink

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

Is it possible to use a post meta value instead of the title as permalink?

I tried different methods, but i did'nt work as i would like

As for now the structure is: www.website../property/post-title

i achived this up to now.. www.website../property/post-meta/post-title

what i would like is: www.website../property/post-meta

my code is:

```
    function property_query_vars( $qv ) {
    $qv[] = 'meta';
    return $qv;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'property_query_vars' );

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'property_post_type_link2', 10, 3);
function property_post_type_link2($permalink, $post, $leavename) {

    if  ($post->post_type == 'property') {
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_boP_prop-id', true);
        $postname = $post->post_name;
        if (isset($meta) && !empty($meta)) 
            $permalink = home_url( " property/" . $meta . "/");

    }

    return $permalink;

}


function mycustomname_rewrites_init2(){
    add_rewrite_rule('property/([^/]*)/?$', 
                     'index.php?post_type=property&meta=$matches[1]', 
                     'top'
    );

}
add_action('init', 'mycustomname_rewrites_init2');
```

this shows the permalink as i wanted but, only the archive page is shown, click on the permalink returns me to archive page.

Comment: I know it may sound as a silly question to you, but why not use the post meta directly as a post title?

Comment: i was thinking also about this XD, the posts for are imported trough a plugin, with uses mapping from a csv file, i changed the mapping, but as it seems it is not possible to use something else as the title in the mapping..

Comment: You can if you change the import file manually. I mean manually change the title to the meta itself. Where do you import the csv? If in database then it's easy to change the csv itself, if custom parser, modify custom parser. Not hard to do.